# Eclipse custom C/C++ code style profile for multiuser environment

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, formatting, eclipse-cdt, preferences

My developers are using Eclipse Helios with CDT 7. I am writing the Eclipse plug-in for this environment. I have created the custom C/C++ code style profile with my new settings named "My Profile". The "My Profile" profile is created and it is in "org.eclipse.cdt.core.prefs" preference file.

I want to set this "My Profile" profile to multi-user environment(i.e global) as default profile.

1. How do I do this on Eclipse start up?
2. How do I do this on my Eclipse Plugin start up?

Answer for 1) is preferable because global preferences are easy in maintenance. Could you please help me on this. Thanks much in advance for the reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link what I am looking for

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/760047/?srch=profilemanager.addProfile#msg_760047